No Internet in Ubuntu Server after updating to 22.04.4 LTS
I have done an update via sudo apt get update && sudo apt upgrade.
I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Also, I have upgraded the Kernel to GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1027-oracle aarch64.
After the update, I wasn't able to access the Instance via SSH.
I can only access the instance via cloud console.
I have a cloud install virtual Maschine with Ubuntu Server hosted on oracle cloud.
I don't know much about networking and have no idea how I can restore Internet access.
I have googled a bit and done these things:
ping 1.1.1.1
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

dig askubuntu.com @1.1.1.1
;; UDP setup with 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) for askubuntu.com failed: network unreachable.
;; no servers could be reached

;; UDP setup with 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) for askubuntu.com failed: network unreachable.
;; no servers could be reached

;; UDP setup with 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) for askubuntu.com failed: network unreachable.
;; no servers could be reached

ip addr gives me the following output:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:17:00:e1:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e95:61d8:aa77:ad19/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:16:0b:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The Output of cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp0s3:
        dhcp4: true
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:00:17:00:e1:21
            set-name: enp0s3

sudo lshw -C network:
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=virtio-pci latency=0
       resources: iomemory:800-7ff irq:48 memory:13001000-13001fff memory:8003008000-800300bfff
     *-virtio1 DISABLED
          description: Ethernet interface
          physical id: 0
          bus info: virtio@1
          logical name: enp0s3
          serial: 02:00:17:00:e1:21
          capabilities: ethernet physical
          configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 link=no multicast=yes

sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces:
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory

Has anyone an idea what I could do?
Tank you very much!

Upgrade and Update do not upgrade the version. You are now using an unsupported kernel. Why are you using a Oracle kernel?

Your netplan YAML does not seem to match your ip addr output. You have, for example, an undeclared bridge virbr0 that has an IP address. Your netplan YAML also seems to come from two nearly duplicate files -- is that intentional?

@David DE The kernel has changed it told me to reboot to load the new kernel. I use the oracle kernel because the machine is hosted on the oracle cloud. Can I go back to the other kernel?

@user535733 no that is not intentional I think I messed this up when I tried installing an openVPN server and Docker.

It does not say in the question this is a cloud install. Please edit the question and add this critical info.

Okay, I habe Updated the question.

try  to generate a new netplan
then apply the changes?
https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/
I have the same problem, altough im not in ubuntu server neither oracle, seems not to come from kernel in my case as i booted with old kernel and the same.
Che
